# How to narrow the type of discriminated union with an optional discriminator

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm writing a React Select-style component that supports either multiple options or just one via an optional `isMulti` boolean. If `isMulti` is not provided, then it should default to `false`.

The approach is described in [this blog post about discriminated unions](https://blog.andrewbran.ch/expressive-react-component-apis-with-discriminated-unions/).

How do I narrow the type of `value` so that TS can correctly infer that `onChange` is being called with the single or multiple OptionValues?

This isn't react code, as this cut-down example shows the error in onChange where

```
type OptionValue = {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}

interface CommonProps {
  className?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  options: OptionValue[];
}

interface SingleValueProps extends CommonProps {
  isMulti?: false;
  value: OptionValue | null;
  onChange: (value: OptionValue) => void;
}

interface MultiValueProps extends CommonProps {
  isMulti: true;
  value: OptionValue[];
  onChange: (value: OptionValue[]) => void;
}

export type Props = SingleValueProps | MultiValueProps;

function Component(props: Props) {
  const value = props.value; // infers OptionValue | OptionValue[] | null

  function handleChange() {
    if (value == null) {
        return
    }

    props.onChange(value) // <- error here
  }

  // Select rendering code will go here
}

// multi
Component({
  isMulti: true,
  value: [],
  onChange: (value) => console.log("value", value), // inferred as  OptionValue[]
  options: []
})

// explicitly not multi
Component({
  isMulti: false,
  value: {label: "x", value: "y"},
  onChange: (value) => console.log("value", value), // inferred as OptionValue
  options: []
})

// not multi (TypeScript infers isMulti as false)
Component({
  value: {label: "x", value: "y"},
  onChange: (value) => console.log("value", value), // inferred as OptionValue
  options: []
})
```

Errors:

```
Errors in code
Argument of type 'OptionValue | OptionValue[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OptionValue & OptionValue[]'.
  Type 'OptionValue' is not assignable to type 'OptionValue & OptionValue[]'.
    Type 'OptionValue' is missing the following properties from type 'OptionValue[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```

[Here's a TypeScript playground of the code above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AagQwDYFdoF4oBvAWACgoosMAjCLALigGdgAnBFAcwG5zKAbtjxNWHbnzIBfcuU7AIbAGYYAxtADCSALbbUABTZIwzYvyirqzZgDkM2iAH5R7Tr3MATBM1pYIH5ygaJCQ-DBRJSmNEVGYmOBj0YQgAbQBdSRkyORQFZTVoAGU3P0xcCENjUwgADwUUD1MtXQMjEzMKKG8AWRwsRECVLGYISKghcvj4ZCTyqAAfKBQ+rDHUDQALcK4IJgAKCZFYadQyvABKKHwAPnGkBA9M2TJ5RRV1KF7+hDOKtuq6hAGk0dHoUJV2qROj0+ogmOw8GNDrtjolfuk1ihNtsUQdklM0cl0pcbncHk9smRamAkGxgFBQJAoBDTIRitxSskWQtPrCflz-pJyEocChVIkoM0aSggcA9mB-kwWZcoZRVLF6cirlAFVUAHTIoWdEViiVbBp+bHcCB7FXkACQCCUUDxc3whGWWCwdrI9vtbAgwBwbBQDqy5ntupMevW5p2rouUAA9EmoAAeAC0UEURjYpg2igg5nDnRTUEK9Ag4qgAYaijcFiQHmgAHcEF6oFwkFACwHyCWy9o+eQpahZXtVV1mF84Qy2HgADTmZFMdJLzqxnH7ZEk27qlDMUIQPVYJBcPYAImRF4X42S51vZe8qJm6LS5miMziUHS-fOzzLaksAQVQEGALAQCWJB6SHb4Rx0aVx0nGFviYIYRnXQR8WIag6EYKALxqG870mAiQAvKRMKgTdrW3e8rj3WIjxPM9L2vW8d0fVNnwSV9kg-E4D1Xd9pH-SkyxQaCoFgxAXQAFXACBClUDh4C6FAlEUUwUNkjBTHQiAxNHGVcgnZdsKIXD6CYQjiJXMiKKomidjo8pd0bA9mNPc8r2SOz7y4qcX1OfiN0E79f1E8ggA)

Comment: I can suggest something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVl6xW). It won't work with not passing the isMulti at all though. Does it work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It's important that `isMulti` is optional, defaulting to `false` if not provided. This follows the react pattern of making boolean attributes default to `false` if they're not provided.

If that's not possible, I'd love an explanation of why :-)

Comment: Try to make the `isMulti` field optional. The compiler will stop inferring the correct types in that case. You will get the union of multi and single variant props

Comment: Hmm, very confusing.  I could refactor to [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WK3EpW) but I don't know if that's what anyone wants to use.

Comment: @jcalz Interesting, any idea why it works :D ?

Comment: I can explain why it works but I can't explain why my prior suggestion *didn't* work.  The generic version of the function can't infer `K`, because the key is gone (it was just a convenience you created; could have been anything), so it fell back to `keyof Props`, and since  `Props[keyof Props]` is a discriminated union, I'd expect the input to be distinguished properly.  By explicitly doing that myself with two functions it works, but no idea what exact failure caused the first not to work.